# How do I make program/app widget start on startup if there is no exe file?

Tags: windows, boot, widgets

So, I am using this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/pomy/9nh2628qfznm?activetab=pivot:overviewtab .
I want it to start at startup but there is no feature in this. I tried making a link to the startup folder but it does not work. I thought about making a bat file (I only know one that I use to shutdown with a timer) but there is no exe file for me to find. Task manager also does not work for the same reason. I have not tried the regedit version, but I doubt because I am not able to find the path.

If there is an exe file, I do not know how to find it because there is no open destination folder option in start menu. There is no desktop shortcut and I can only make a link to the one in the start folder.

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Did you research starting Windows 10 store apps on start up? Because I ran a web search and found a half dozen results including from Microsoft.com noting how to do precisely this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/4558286/windows-10-add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup

1. Select the Start  button and scroll to find the app you want to run at startup.
2. Right-click the app, select More, and then select Open file location. This opens the location where the shortcut to the app is saved. If there isn't an option for Open file location, it means the app can't run at startup.
3. With the file location open, press the Windows logo key  + R, type shell:startup, then select OK. This opens the Startup folder.
4. Copy and paste the shortcut to the app from the file location to the Startup folder.

Comment: I did this. If you read my question, this is the first item in the list of things that I did that did not work. I made a link to the startup folder and it does not work.

Comment: It doesn't say link to the Startup Folder, it says to copy the app shortcut to the Startup Folder. Please note the answer also notes there are apps that cannot be run on start up and how to tell.

Comment: It is working now.